# Why PJSip in android not working properly?

Tags: android, pjsip

I have tried Apjsua project build it from the pjsip.org doesn't got success. i spent lot of time on that still it's not registering properly. if any one of you have successfully build apjsua sample app then please help me.

I googled lot for sip, many peoples are suggesting me to use CSipSimple but i need more options than csipsimple features. so i tried to build pjsip app. but no success. Does anyone have any experience with pjsip on android devices ? share with me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean "registering properly"? do you have problem with registering sip user or with building apjsua

Comment: unable to register with my account name and password. i gave all the information in the cfg file properly still not able to register.

Comment: I do not have much experience with PJSIP because I just started too, and I didn't use a configuration file yet so i can't help you with this. But I tested the functionality of the "console appliacation" (Application Menus) and all functions in main menu works good. At the beginning of the program I'm using a function to register etc. Now i'm trying to modify and improve it. You can also try to register this way.

Comment: how u did for registration, are u using pjsip ?

Comment: Yes, i'm using pjsip and. I successfully build an application "apjsua" and run on device. Application looks like "console" and you have "char" options. And there is a command "+a" to add new account, when you add an account it should automatically register you on sipserver. Do you have same application?

Comment: i have same application but how to add account when i click on "+a". now i m using cfg file for adding account details with usename, server password realm etc, if i did't use cfg file how to add these basic informations into the app..if it possible can u send me the sample app.it should be look like modified version in JNI code..

Comment: I added answer. Also if you want to see how console application works you should check this file  "pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/main.c"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

When you start application you should have a menu. Now type

```
+a
```

After that console should ask for more information, for example:

1. sip:username@sipserver
2. sip:sipserver
3. *
4. username
5. password

After that you should be logged. But before this you should change "setInput" function in pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/main_android.c on:

```
void setInput(char *s)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(app_var.line); i++)
    {
        app_var.line[i]=NULL;
    }

    if (strlen(s) < sizeof(app_var.line))
        strncpy(app_var.line, s, strlen(s));

    pj_sem_post(app_var.input_sem);
}
```

Comment: where i have to set these parameters : sip:username@sipserver
sip:sipserver
*
username
password

Comment: in command line (EditText) and confirm. So after typing "+a" press confirm, after that you should type "sip:username@sipserver" and press confirm, etc. Is it works?

Comment: I am new to this JNI concepts so not able to getting this what i have to do here.

Comment: Ok so when you run application on android device you have Menu and EditText like here http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm#menu yes?

Comment: yes, now i am  able to those menu..then what have to do next. i mean how to give inputs to the console those all informations like username etc..

Comment: Ok you have Menu and EditText and now click on EditText and type "+a" after that it should ask you for more info and you should get msg:  "Your SIP URL: (empty to cancel)". Have you got this?

Comment: And don't forget to confirm your input with return button on soft keyboard.